# Best approach to embed subquery results

Tags: sql

Currently I have a web application (JSF 2.0 and SQL Server) where values for tDataTable are retrieved using a Query A  and then based on retrieved result we run another query to retrieve associated details.

for example :
Query A: returns all Restaurants in User selected Area (let's imagine there are 1000s)
Query B: Based on Returned Result (Above) , Query B retries reviews for each restaurant using the RestaurantPK value.

So the way it's done now, if there are 200 rows once Query A has executed, We call Query B 200 Times to retrieve review information for each restaurant.

So my question is how can i make more efficient? What is the standard practice in these cases? I chose the title as "Best approach to embed Sub-query result" as i suspect a sub-query will need to be used in Query A , but cannot figure out how it would work, given for each restaurant(Row) there could be 10-15 reviews).

### UPDATE:

I had tried JOIN before posting my question here but problem was i was only getting one review for each restaurant instead of all available reviews for each restaurant. I'm starting to think the only way to do this would be to Write a storedProcedure where once A is executed I'll store the result in a #temp table, loop through the result and retrieve all the reviews for each restaurant and insert them back into the #temp table where if one resturant has 10 reviews, they will be separated by ; and back in java I'll split them back into a meaningful format. that way i am still returning just one row for each restaurant but with embedded reviews as one of columns.

so i would have:

Resturnat, Location, Phone......Reviews
X,Sydney,1234,.....,AAAAAAA;BBBBBBBB;CCCCCCCCC;

Comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said how you are 'displaying' this data so can't recommend an absolute best approach. I would say your 2 options are

1. A join that returns all reviews - the restaurant information will be duplicated for each row so when displaying you should loop through and check if the current row's RestaurantPK is different to the previous and only display the info then.
2. Return 2 tables form the SQL server. Load the results of Query A into a @temp or #temp table and then do something like

   SELECT * from @temp

   SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE RestaurantPK IN (SELECT RestaurantPK from @temp)

although obviously selecting your columns by name rather than *

Comment: Thanks, I am going with this approach , 2 SQL selects inside a stored procedure .. definitely an improvement over the precious method we were using

Answer (score 2):

Use joins in SQL, so you can get all data in 1 query.:

```
Select rest.id, reviews.text 
from restaurants rest
inner join reviews on reviews.rest_id = rest.id
where some conditions for restaurants
```

Comment: thanks for reply - can check my updated question and comment?